# JavescriptInterface and thread not returning to main thread

Tags: javascript, android, multithreading, webview

I'm developing a app for android and some of the content is displayed via a WebView.

I have an interface for Javascript like this.

```
WebAppInterface(Context c, Response response) {
        activity = (Activity) c;
        delegate = response;
        context = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void getResponse(final String operation, final String response, final String type) {
        final Handler mainHandler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());
        mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                delegate.didGetResponse(operation, response, type);
                Log.d("Success: ", "Im still here"); <-- why am I not back in main thread? 
            }
        });    
    }

    public interface Response {
        public void didGetResponse(String operation, String response, String type);
    }
```

My activity implements didGetResponse and have a switch which executes code and update the webview if needed but only on the first function in the webview so after the page is set the webview does not respond to anymore "clicks"

I'm thinking its because the thread is still in the javascriptinterface?

However native buttons can still update the webview. But I want to be able to call the js functions from the newly loaded url in the webview

Comment: Okay I narrowed it down to a "Uncaught Error: Method not found" when I click a element in the newly loaded url

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so I found the answer it turns out that I was calling a javascript function with to little arguments. So my solution worked and the problem was my js function only had 2 arguments instead of 3 on this page. this is different from swift where it did work with just the 2 arguments.

Comment: +1 I was also getting "Uncaught Error: Method not found" and it was because on the Javascript side I was calling the function with 1 argument, but the native side was exposing a method that expected 2 arguments.

Comment: Thanks - was pulling my hair out. A case where the error message is both completely accurate and largely misleading. :)